# why is the serial.print function not printing the entire string?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

This code is running on an arduino but I imagine the output would be similar with any serial print function on any device. The output I get on the serial monitor is

```
1st line hello world
1st line
```

However I expected the output would be

```
1st line hello world
1st line hello world
```

I cant understand why the rest of the string isn't printed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
char charBuffer[1024];

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  appendCharBuffer("1st line ");
  appendCharBuffer("hello ");
  appendCharBuffer("world ");

  for(int i = 0; i<=21; i++)
  {
  Serial.print(charBuffer[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(charBuffer);
  while(1){}
}

void appendCharBuffer(const char * message)
{
  static int bufferIndex = 0;
  if (bufferIndex >= 950)
  {
    appendFile(charBuffer);
    bufferIndex = 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i<=strlen(message); i++)
  {
    charBuffer[bufferIndex] = message[i];
    bufferIndex++;
  }

}
```

Comment: Just a heads up so that you don't get surprises later: This is a C++ program. A C compiler would not be able to compile this. Also note: `while(1){}` at the end of `loop()` will put it in an infinitive loop.

Comment: `appendCharBuffer` copies the terminating 0 character to the buffer the first time you call it. The next time you call it you're appending to the buffer after that 0. `Serial.println` stops at the first 0 it sees.

Comment: arduino is C++ not C

Answer (score -1):

```
void appendCharBuffer(const char * message)
{
  static int bufferIndex = 0;
  size_t len;

  if(!message) bufferIndex = 0;
  else 
  {
      len = strlen(message);
      strncpy(charBuffer + bufferIndex, message, sizeof(charBuffer) - bufferIndex);
      bufferIndex += len;
  }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/sesW14W5e

Comment: An explanation would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My function must have printed a 0 to the end of the string. I did actually try
    if (message[i] != '\0')
    {
      charBuffer[bufferIndex] = message[i];
    }
    but I got the same result. Thanks for the above code, a much better implementation of what I'm trying to achieve. Cheers